# Limit $\lim_{z\to i\pi} \left( z-i\pi \right)\frac{e^z}{1+e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm about to finding a residue at $z\to i\pi$, but I'm stuck in finding the limit:

$$\lim_{z\to i\pi} \left( z-i\pi \right)\frac{e^z}{1+e^z}$$

What are the steps to eliminate the $z-i\pi$ part and $1+e^z$ part?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z):=e^z$. Then

$$\frac{e^z+1}{z-i \pi}=\frac{f(z)-f( i \pi)}{z-i \pi} \to f'( i \pi)$$

as $z \to  i \pi.$

Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that that limit is equal to$$\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to i\pi}e^z}{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to i\pi}\frac{e^z-e^{i\pi}}{z-i\pi}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $$\frac{1+e^z}{z-i\pi} = \frac{e^z - e^{i\pi}}{z- i\pi}$$

Taking the limit should make appear a derivative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$y= \left( z-i\pi \right)\frac{e^z}{1+e^z}$$ Let  $z=x+i \pi$ to make
$$y=\frac{e^x x}{e^x-1}$$ since $e^{i \pi}=-1$. Now, use composition of Taylor series around $x=0$.

When done, replace $x$ by $z-i \pi$